# Can not invoke managed bean Action method from DojoFaces button component

Tags: jsf, dojo

I am trying to use DojoFaces in my next JSF based portlet. I am using JSF 1.1 with JSR 286 portlets to be deployed on WPS 6.1.

Problem is, I am using  with action attribute, which has should invoke the JSF managed bean action method. BUT, it doesnt not.

```
<dojo:button id="myBtn" label="DOJOSubmit" attr="type: 'submit'" rendered="true"      
action="\#{myBean.myAction}">    </dojo:button>
```

Interestingly, I created one phaseListener just to check what happens when I click on the button. I noted, it goes through all phases but "Invoke Applcation". As below,

```
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:RESTORE_VIEW 1
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:RESTORE_VIEW 1
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:RESTORE_VIEW 1
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:RESTORE_VIEW 1
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
[20/09/11 17:29:13:355 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
[20/09/11 17:29:13:386 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:RESTORE_VIEW 1
[20/09/11 17:29:13:386 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:RESTORE_VIEW 1
[20/09/11 17:29:13:402 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:RESTORE_VIEW 1
[20/09/11 17:29:13:402 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:RESTORE_VIEW 1
[20/09/11 17:29:13:402 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:RENDER_RESPONSE 6
[20/09/11 17:29:13:402 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O Before:RENDER_RESPONSE 6
[20/09/11 17:29:13:402 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:RENDER_RESPONSE 6
[20/09/11 17:29:13:402 BST] 0000013a SystemOut     O AFTER:RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

Can someone explain me why this is happening?

Regards
HP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ganesh of Dojofaces, I got it right.

Problem was that I left the input component without binding it for values with the managed bean as below, which should be avoided.

```
<dojo:form id="dojoForm">
<dojo:textBox id="dftextbox" attr="" value="" />

<dojo:button id="tundraButton" label="DOJOSubmit" attr="type: 'submit'" rendered="true" action="\#{myBean.myAction}">         
</dojo:button>    

</dojo:form>
```

And hence, as suggested I attached textBox with a value of a managed bean as below,

```
<dojo:textBox id="dftextbox" attr="" value="#{myBean.myText}" />
```

And that's it. It worked for me.

Hope this helps someone !